# Mod_proxy rewrite rule help for /foo/ to /foo/index.html

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-proxy, proxypass

With mod_proxy I need to redirect /foo/ requests to /foo/index.html. So if a user types in : https://example.com/foo/ they should be redirected to https://example.com/foo/index.html

I tried the following rule but it does not work:

```
<Location /foo/>
  RequestHeader set Host example.com
</Location>
ProxyPass         /foo/      https://example.com/foo/index.html
ProxyPassReverse  /foo/      https://example.com/foo/index.html
```

While this works for any requests to https://example.com/foo/*, it does not work for https://example.com/foo/. Any help on what I can use for the redirect to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a normal redirect to index.html before the request hits the proxy.

```
<Location /foo/>
  RequestHeader set Host example.com
</Location>
RewriteRule ^/foo(/|)$ /foo/index.html [NC] 
ProxyPass         /foo/      https://example.com/foo/
ProxyPassReverse  /foo/      https://example.com/foo/
```

Comment: There's no way to just use ProxyPass directives for this?

Comment: It doesn't seem to do the redirect. I get a 403